# Google Sheets Named Range - reference single cell and enable pull-down

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula, formula, named-ranges

I am trying to simplify my google sheet with named ranges to not be driven nuts by the formulas I have built. I have named quite some ranges and now I am trying to replace the cell references, e.g. `C22` with the named range cell name. So far I used `INDEX`, so `INDEX(age,1)`, which has not been a great idea for what I want to achieve.

Unfortunately, when I use this in a formula that I want to "pull down" just as I would do with a traditional formula, which would return C23, C24, ... the index example stays the same and is not dynamic. What could I use instead of INDEX to make this happen?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try like this:

```
=INDEX(age, ROW(A1))
```

Comment: This is awesome - I did not get first that A1 references the first row and column within the named range. Thanks so much

Comment: Reference to the solution used: [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) will return the row number of the cell referenced allowing you to drop down the formula and propagating it to the rest of the cells.

Comment: Expanding on what @MateoRandwolf commented:

`A1` does not reference the first row and column of the named range - it references the actual `A1` cell of the sheet. `ROW(A1)` will always return `1`, and so `=INDEX(age, ROW(A1)` is equivalent to `=INDEX(age, 1)`.

The reason this works for "pulling down" is that the `A1` reference will be updated relatively, and the formula will be updated to use `ROW(A2)`, `ROW(A3)`, etc. which will evaluate to `2`, `3`, etc.